# Angular2 bootstrap from outside typescript file, directly from html page

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular-bootstrap

I have existing website, which is build with `angular1+requirejs` and `php`. I would like to add `angular2` (which I have already added, using `angular2-cli`).

I don't need `angular1` to communicate with `angular2`, so we don't have to do `ng-upgrade`

I want to bootstrap `angular2` components outside `app component` `typescript` file.

I'm bit confused on how to do this, because everything is in typescript and after compiled, they are completely different.

I'm trying to load different component per page, sometime one and sometime more then one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, first to all you need to provide more information. But, on the big picture, you have create a root module and declare component that belong to it, the same for directives and so on. Ex.

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import
       { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

bootstraping the module:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

anyway, you can check this to get some idea [ngModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html)

This is how to boostrap with javascript.
Creating module:

```
(function(app) {
  app.AppModule =
    ng.core.NgModule({
      imports: [ ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule ],
      declarations: [ app.AppComponent ],
      bootstrap: [ app.AppComponent ]
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {}
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

bootstraping:

```
(function(app) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ng.platformBrowserDynamic
      .platformBrowserDynamic()
      .bootstrapModule(app.AppModule);
  });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Comment: I'm trying to bootstrap outside typescript. Is there any possibility with that?

Comment: You need to use typescript to declare the directives you're using. You only need to bootstrap once, and your bootstrap code can be super general - each of your pages can still live in their own component w/o any bootstrap code needed per page.